# Problems validating value of select for ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that if the user selects a value of 1 the form is submitted but if they select 2 or 3 they have to select a value from the select with the class `reason select` (there are three selects with the class `reason select`, I have just shown one this question to keep the code as short as poss)

the html which is wrapped in a div called `audit_content`

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <select name="grade" class="grade" >
            <option value="1">1 - Perfect</option>
            <option value="2">2 - Diagnostic</option>
            <option value="3">3 - Unusable</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="exposure_reason" class="reason_select" >
            <option value="1">Reason One</option>
            <option value="2">Reason Two</option>
            <option value="3">Reason Three</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="button" class="delete_submit delete_from_audit" value=""
        onClick="delete_image('<? echo $image_id; ?>','<? echo $audit_id; ?>')" />
    <input type="button" class="reset_grade control_submit ie7_reset"     
        onclick="reset_image('<? echo $image_id; ?>','<? echo $audit_id; ?>')" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" class="form_id" value="<? echo $i; ?>" >
    <input type="button" name="audit_submit"
        class="audit_submit audit_submit_btn ie7_submit" value="" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

the jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#audit_content').on("click", ".audit_submit", function(){
      var form_id = $(this).prev('.form_id').val();
      alert(form_id);
      var $form = $(this);
      reasonHasVal = false;
      if ($form.find('select[name="grade"]').val() != "1") {
       $form.find("select.reason_select").each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() != "") {
               reasonHasVal = true;
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/image_audit.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $('#audit_form'+form_id).serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                $('.audited_ok_tick'+form_id).html(response);
            },
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(thrownError);
        }
     });
     return false;
    }
       });
       if (!reasonHasVal) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("Please select a reason.");
       }
     } 
  });
});
```

When I click the submit button the alert with the `form_id` works but nothing else, I know the ajax call is ok because it worked until I tried to add the validation for the select values

Comment: Too much HTML is missing for me to further investigate...

Comment: which bit of the html do you need? the whole lot is about 600 lines

Comment: The part that is referred to in the posted JS (e.g. the `.form_id` etc). A **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** or a **[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** would also help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a couple of problems:

First, you should be seeing an error in your console because you call `e.preventDefault()` but `e` is not defined.  So when registering the anonymous function for the `click` event, you need to add `e`:

```
$('#audit_content').on("click", ".audit_submit", function (e) {
```

Secondly, `$form` will be a reference to your button, and `$form.find('select[name="grade"]')` will always be empty.  Maybe it would be more clear if you post all your code, but I guess you're intention is to have each question posted separately and they are identified by the `form_id`?  I'm guessing somewhere not shown, maybe a common table, the `form_id` value is used as the id for the element.  In that case you'll need this code instead:

```
var $form = $(this).parents('#' + form_id);
```

If my assumption is correct, then everything else should work correctly.  If my assumption is incorrect, well you need to find some better way to find the input controls.  Some alternatives are:

```
var $form = $(this).parents('table');
var $form = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
```

Comment: the table is one of many created using a while loop, the form_id is used to identify the correct div to display the ajax result, I'll add a bit more info to my question.  I'm afraid the correction you suggested now always asks to select a reason but does nothing else, but thanks anyway

Comment: @tatty27, I mistakenly had `parent` instead of `parents`,  makes a big difference

Comment: Yeah, everything else should work...well of course...except for the fact that the form will never be submitted if the user selects "1" in the first select and about a dozen more errors and typos... :)

Comment: @DanielGimenez still didn't work but it's getting there, I will cut it back and start adding to it using the suggestions you made, thanks

Comment: @ExpertSystem , I know there are typos and errors, thats why it doesn't work and why I asked for help.  I'm trying to learn jquery and ajax

Comment: @tatty27: I know, that's why I am pointing it out, so that you don't get disappointed when it does not work "out-of-the-box". If you want a few suggestions: Try to eliminate the typos (so people trying to help you out can focus on the real problems) and provide all the code necessary to pinpoint the real problems (so people trying to help you out don't waste typo speculating what might `.form_id` refer to ) ;)

Comment: @tatty27: BTW, it is customary to also upvote the answer you marked as accepted. It is not obligatory, of course, but it sure makes sense...